# can I use javascript in typescriptFile?

Tags: javascript, typescript

hi I'm get started typescript. 
I studied that typescript is javascript's super set So We can use javascript 
in Typescript File.

I'm wrote this code.

```
const words = '1,2,3,4'.split(',');
let sum = 0;
words.forEach(w => sum += parseInt(w));
console.log('sum:   ${sum}');
```

that's output should be in console

> sum: 10

but that's result was

> sum:   ${sum}

I studied that  in ES6 ' ${} 'means expression like Kotlin
can I use ES6 expression in TS ?
I'm using WEBSTORM

Comment: need to use backticks \`sum: ${sum}\`

Comment: you should enclose inside backTicks **``** `sum: ${sum}`

Comment: thank you very much!! it's work!!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the string with back ticks (`) instead of single quotes (') and it will work.

Comment: my comment answers this